# Inheritance and (automatic?) type conversion

Tags: scala

Please have a look at the followin code, where `Extractor[A,B]` is part of a generic framework and everything else should be regarded as "client code" (I boiled it a down quite a bit and renamed everything. So don't mind that `Extractor` doesn't seem to be too usefull).

```
scala> abstract class Extractor[A,B] {                                          
     |   def extract(d:A):B                                                     
     |   def stringRepr(d:A):String                                             
     | }                                                                        
defined class Extractor

scala> sealed abstract class Value                                              
defined class Value

scala> case class IntValue(i:Int) extends Value                                 
defined class IntValue

scala> case class StringValue(s:String) extends Value                           
defined class StringValue

scala> case class Data(i:Int, s:String)                                         
defined class Data

scala> sealed abstract class MyExtractor[Value] extends Extractor[Data, Value] {
     |   def stringRepr(d:Data) = extract(d) match {                            
     |     case IntValue(i) => i.toString                                       
     |     case StringValue(s) => s                                             
     |   }                                                                      
     | }                                                                        
defined class MyExtractor

scala> class IntExtractor(name:String) extends MyExtractor[IntValue] {
     |   def extract(d:Data) = IntValue(d.i)
     | }
defined class IntExtractor

scala> class StringExtractor(name:String) extends MyExtractor[StringValue] {
     |   def extract(d:Data) = StringValue(d.s)
     | }
defined class StringExtractor
```

so in short words `Extractor[A,B]` is used to extract some value `B` from `A` and do some other things that are not represented in this show code. The abstract classes `Value` and `MyExtractor` are used for reasons of type savety in the "client code".
When I try to create a `List` of `MyExtractor`s, the following happens:

```
scala> val l = List.empty[MyExtractor[Value]]
l: List[MyExtractor[Value]] = List()

scala> new IntExtractor("test1") :: l
res5: List[MyExtractor[_ >: IntValue <: Value]] = List(IntExtractor@1fd96c5)
```

trying to convert an `IntExractor` to a superclass

```
scala> new IntExtractor("test"):MyExtractor[Value]   
<console>:24: error: type mismatch;
 found   : IntExtractor
 required: MyExtractor[Value]
       new IntExtractor("test"):MyExtractor[Value]
       ^

scala> new IntExtractor("test"):Extractor[Data,Value]
<console>:24: error: type mismatch;
 found   : IntExtractor
 required: Extractor[Data,Value]
       new IntExtractor("test"):Extractor[Data,Value]
```

I am aware that everything is fine, when I define `IntExtractor` like this

```
scala> class IntExtractor(name:String) extends MyExtractor[Value] {
     |   def extract(d:Data) = IntValue(d.i)                            
     | }
defined class IntExtractor

scala> new IntExtractor("test"):Extractor[Data,Value]              
res17: Extractor[Data,Value] = IntExtractor@1653d7a
```

But I don't understand, why it doesn't work the way I tried it above.
I would be thankfull for any help or hints.

Comment: As a general rule, it's helpful not to use the names of actual classes for type parameters. E.g., in `class MyExtractor[Value]` the `Value` is a type parameter and has nothing to do with your `class Value`. This use of names tends to be confusing to humans, though of course it never fazes the compiler.

Comment: Your `Extractor[A,B]` behaves a lot like a `A => B` (i.e. a `Function1`). Note that `Function1` is covariant in its return type - it is declared as `Function1[-A,+B]`

Comment: @ Randall Schulz: I'm not 100% shure I understand you right but the `Value` in `class MyExtractor[Value]` DOES correspond with the `class Value`. For example I'm only checking for subclasses of `Value` in `stringRepr(d:Value):String`

Comment: @ oxbow_lakes: yes I'm aware of the `A => B` connection (and thanks for pointing that out. It made me define the additional function `apply(d:A):B = extract(d)` ;) ). But as mentioned this is only a boiled down version of my code to produce the error without all the other stuff. In real life `Extractor` is called `ColumnDescription` and will represent a column in a `Table`. It will also manage the rendering, editing, sorting, name and everything if this column. So `extract(d:A):B` is really only a small subset of it's functionality.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As near as I can tell, the concept you are looking for is "covariance".  Just because `IntValue` is a subtype of `Value` doesn't mean that `MyExtractor[IntValue]` is a subtype of `MyExtractor[Value]`.  By default, there is no subtyping relation between those two types at all.  To create such a relationship, you need to declare `MyExtractor` to be covariant with respect to it's parameter.  Scala lets you declare type parameters to be covariant by adding a "+" before the type parameters declaration.  This is called a variance notation.

```
sealed abstract class MyExtractor[+Value] extends Extractor[Data, Value] {        
}
```

Scala also supports contravariance over type parameters.   Contravariance is just like covariance, but reversed, and is expressed with a "-" variance notation on the type parameter.  Your `Extractor` type provides an excellent example of a place where a contravariance notation makes sense.

```
abstract class Extractor[-A,+B] {                                          
   def extract(d:A):B                                                     
   def stringRepr(d:A):String                                             
}
```

This means that if `Foo` is a subtype of `Bar`, then `Extractor[Bar, Baz]` is a subtype of `Extractor[Foo, Baz]`, which if you think about it makes sense.  If something can extract the data you want when passed an instance of a supertype, then by definition it can extract it when passed an instance of a subtype.  Conversely, if `Foo` is a subtype of `Bar`, then `Extractor[Baz, Foo]` is a subtype of `Extractor[Baz, Bar]`.  That also makes sense. If you've got an extractor that returns a `Foo`, you can certainly use it wherever you need an extractor that returns a `Bar`.

There are restrictions on when contravariance and covariance can be declared.   For instance, contravariant type parameters can only be used as method arguments, and covariant parameters can only be used as method returns or vals.  Neither can be used as vars.  It gets more complicated with nested type parameters, but the rules basically boil down to "where it's sensible", and your example meets all of them.

Additional side note, all of your abstract classes in your example should probably be declared as traits instead.   As long as your abstract classes don't require constructor arguments, declaring them as traits gives you a few more opportunities for reuse.

Comment: wow! thanks for your answer Dave. To make a long story short: changed everything as you said and it works. Thank you! To make it a little lnger: now that you pointed it out it's really obvious (even the restrictions) although I still can't get my head around that contravariance thing . . . still got some thinking to do ;). I used abstract classes since I didn't know, that traits could have the modifier `sealed`. But then again . . . why not? ;) Thanks a lot