# Covariant Typeparameter in scala needs to be invariant in java interface

Tags: java, generics, scala, scala-2.8

I've got a trait that looks like this (some further information can be found at [this related question by myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695990/inheritance-and-automatic-type-conversion) although I don't think, it's needed for this question)

```
trait Extractor[-A,+B] {
  def extract(d:A):B
  //lots of other things
}
```

To use this in an existing java framework I would like this `Extractor` to either have a function that returns a `Comparator[B]` (being [java.util.Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)) or even better extend `Comparator[A]`. Now that poses a problem because `Comparator`s type parameter is ought to be invariant, while `A` is contravariant and `B` is covariant.

So I get errors like this:

```
scala> import java.util.Comparator
import java.util.Comparator

scala> trait Extractor[-A,+B] extends Comparator[A]
<console>:6: error: contravariant type A occurs in invariant position in type [-A,+B]java.lang.Object with java.util.Comparator[A] of trait Extractor
       trait Extractor[-A,+B] extends Comparator[A]
             ^


scala> trait Extractor[-A, +B] {                 
     |   def comp:Comparator[B]
     | }
<console>:7: error: covariant type B occurs in invariant position in type => java.util.Comparator[B] of method comp
         def comp:Comparator[B]
             ^
```

Do you see any way out of this or is this just one of those cases where "using java generics in scala hurts"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With help of type-bounds it's possible to do the following:

```
scala> trait Extractor[-A, +B] {
     | def comp:Comparator[_ <: B]
     | }
defined trait Extractor
```

Comment: thanks. That works. The code is not running yet but your code and the effective declaration of the Comparator compile save and sound. Thank you so much.

Comment: I know this is a whole different question but is there a good paper/tutorial/blog covering type-bounds and variants? I already read about it but one could argue that I didn't learn too much from them ;) (on the other hand, maybe that's just me. So all read them all again)

Comment: This one is pretty good (though it's not up-to-date -- doesn't have information about some 2.8 features) : http://programming-scala.labs.oreilly.com/ch12.html

Comment: until i DO read more about this, just let me make sure, I understand what you are doing here. `[_ <: B]` says "what ever the type parameter may be, it has to be a subtype of `B`". Right? Shouldn't (in a perfect world) this information derive from the usage of `+B` in `Extractor[-A, +B]`?

Comment: Thanks for the reading material. Already planed to work my way through that book . . .

Answer (score 7):

You can make `Extractor[A,B]` extend `Comparator[A]` by using the `@uncheckedVariance` annotation.

```
scala> import scala.annotation.unchecked.uncheckedVariance
import scala.annotation.unchecked.uncheckedVariance

scala> trait Extractor[-A,+B] extends java.util.Comparator[A @uncheckedVariance]
defined trait Extractor
```

`@uncheckedVariance` is safe here because `Comparator` could have been defined as `Comparator[-T]`.  There was a [discussion](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/3786) around making `Ordering` covariant for Scala 2.8 using this annotation.

**Edit** See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454281/when-is-uncheckedvariance-needed-in-scala-and-why-is-it-used-in-generictraversa) for more about `@uncheckedVariance`.

Comment: uh that's a nice one too. Actually this could be the version that ends up in my code . . . as soon as I find the time to read that thread you posted. Thanks a lot!